How to add header icon to parent in children screen material-top-bar?
I have material top tab screen to render 2 children screen i want to add header right icon in parent screen.
Now I'm in GPRDetailView screen and I want to add header right icon in parent screen GPR.
I try using navigation.setOptions({}), but it doesn't work.
This is my header tab code:
const HeaderTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator()
function GoodsPurchaseRequest() {
    const theme = useTheme()
    return (
        <HeaderTab.Navigator initialRouteName="GPRDetailView"
            screenOptions={{tabBarStyle: {backgroundColor: theme.colors.background}}}
        >
            <HeaderTab.Screen
                name="GPRDetailView"
                component={GPRDetailView}
                options={{
                    title: 'GPR DETAILS',
                }}
            />
            <HeaderTab.Screen
                name="GPREApproval"
                component={GPREApproval}
                options={{
                    title: 'E-APPROVAL',
                }}
            />
        </HeaderTab.Navigator>
    )
}

function Authorized() {
    const theme = useTheme()
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={GPRAddForm} />
            <Stack.Screen name="GPR" component={GoodsPurchaseRequest} />
         </Stack.Navigator>
    )
}

